# не могу понять, в чем ошибка mysql

Tags: mysql

Пишу функцию в db forge. Он генерит свои строки 
    Пишу функцию в db forge, он автоматически при создании функции генерит свои строки

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost'
    FUNCTION football.func_3(T_id integer(10))
    RETURNS INT
    BEGIN
    select count(*)
    FROM teams, games
    WHERE  ((teams.Team_id=games.Team_1_id
    AND teams.id=T_id ) OR 
    (teams.Team_id=games.Team_2_id
    AND teams.id=T_id));
    RETURN 1;
    END
```

при сохранении выдает ошибку Not allowed to return a result set from a function
и выделяет сгенеренную первую строку. Что может быть?

Comment: Ошибка прямо дословно вам говорит, что из функции нельзя вернуть result set. т.е. любой select внутри функции должен возвращать результат в какую нибудь переменную (переменные), т.е. использовать ключевое слово INTO